# sys.argv : list indedx out of range

Tags: python, indexing

part of script

```
if sys.argv[1]  == 'help':
    help()
elif len(sys.argv) < 5:
    use()
else:
    pass


host = sys.argv[1]
username = sys.argv[2]
password = sys.argv[3]
node = sys.argv[4]
opts = sys.argv[5]
```

this is just part of code where problem is occuring.. when i run it , error occured :

```
host = sys.argv[1]
```

IndexError: list index out of range

All were working well, but i just reinstalled python. But, now it is creating problem. This is well working in linux still.

" Through some search, i came to know that '.py association in the registry is incorrect. It's missing %* at the end.'  but, i don't know how to fix it.

Current setup path in environment variable is C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:
\Python27\Scripts\

Comment: could you show us the command line you call the python script with ?

Comment: Always check the (minimal required) length of the a list before trying to call the entries (in this case; parameters). You have to evaluate your input.

Comment: Again to mention :

All were working well, but i just reinstalled python. But, now it is creating problem. This is well working in linux still.

" Through some search, i came to know that '.py association in the registry is incorrect. It's missing %* at the end.' but, i don't know how to fix it.

Current setup path in environment variable is C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C: \Python27\Scripts\

Comment: i came  across one Q with same problem asked before some years on SO

here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690150/python-sys-argv-out-of-range-dont-understand-why?answertab=votes#comment9359563_7690545

Comment: *please*, could you at least show us the command line you call the script with ( like `python my_script.py 1 toto coucou "2013-01-01"` for example) and/or write as the first first line of your script `print str(sys.argv)`

Answer (score 3):

`sys.argv` is a list like any other, except that it's created from the command line.

It has as many items as are indicated by the command line you use to run the script.

The code was never correct and the problem is nothing to do with your Python file associations or your path. (If it were, you'd be getting an error from the command line, but instead you are getting an error that comes from Python.)

The problem is that you assume there will be a `sys.argv[1]`, by checking for `'help'` before any check on the length of `sys.argv`. If the script is run with no arguments at all, then that `[1]` index is out of range.

Comment: no even after giving arguments.. it is not working..

Also, again to mention it is working well in linux and was working well before i reinstalled python on windows too

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the program to show you what it thinks `sys.argv` contains?

Comment: i tried all , even made a customized another script. even thatz not working well

Comment: @Lady Just type `print sys.argv` at the start of your script and see what happens

Comment: i came  across one Q with same problem asked before some years on SO

here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690150/python-sys-argv-out-of-range-dont-understand-why?answertab=votes#comment9359563_7690545